# Kafka Producer cannot validate record wihout PK and return InvalidRecordException

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have error with my kafka producer. I use Debezium Kafka connectors V1.1.0 Final and Kafka 2.4.1 . For tables with pk, all tables are flushed clearly, but unfortunately for tables with no pk on it, it give me this error:

```
[2020-04-14 10:00:00,096] INFO   Exporting data from table 'public.table_0' (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:280)
[2020-04-14 10:00:00,097] INFO   For table 'public.table_0' using select statement: 'SELECT * FROM "public"."table_0"' (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:287)
[2020-04-14 10:00:00,519] INFO   Finished exporting 296 records for table 'public.table_0'; total duration '00:00:00.421' (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:330)
[2020-04-14 10:00:00,522] INFO Snapshot - Final stage (io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource:79)
[2020-04-14 10:00:00,523] INFO Snapshot ended with SnapshotResult [status=COMPLETED, offset=PostgresOffsetContext [sourceInfo=source_info[server='postgres'db='xxx, lsn=38/C74913C0, txId=4511542, timestamp=2020-04-14T02:00:00.517Z, snapshot=FALSE, schema=public, table=table_0], partition={server=postgres}, lastSnapshotRecord=true]] (io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator:90)
[2020-04-14 10:00:00,524] INFO Connected metrics set to 'true' (io.debezium.pipeline.metrics.StreamingChangeEventSourceMetrics:59)
[2020-04-14 10:00:00,526] INFO Starting streaming (io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator:100)
[2020-04-14 10:00:00,550] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=pg_dev_pinjammodal-0} failed to send record to table_0: (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:347)
org.apache.kafka.common.InvalidRecordException: This record has failed the validation on broker and hence be rejected.
```

I have check the tables and it seem valid record. I set my producer `producer.ack=1` in my config. Is this config trigger the invalidity in here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem was **creating Kafka topics with log compaction for non-PK tables**, which need keys. The messages don't have keys, because the tables don't have PKs. This results in the brokers not being able to validate the Kafka messages.

The solution is to not set log compaction to the topics and/or not pre-creating those topics. Another option would be to add PKs to the tables.

Comment: I was getting `.InvalidRecordException: One or more records have been rejected` error cos at the time of topic creationg i was using `--config cleanup.policy=compact` option. Removing this option solved my problem

Comment: How do you manage to add PK to those tables if we do not have installed kSql?
Im having the same issue when restartinh schema registry.

Comment: I don't use KSQL or confluent and rely on pure kafka from scratch. So in your case @Javier the only way is to shut down the sink for the table, truncate it and restructure the table PK. 

Or in other case, if not using PK is intentional, i recommend to not use compaction for that table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i use confluent images but community edition, son no visual IDEs of any kind, and also no kSql yet, but i create topics and schemas with the scripts given by kafka so i dont know what tables you mean of, i still dont know i we require compacting but it seems fair to try to keep records for now.
How can i reach these tables you mean? are they topic tables or schemas?

Comment: I stumbled across the same problem, following the Kafka tutorial. You might want to mention the specific parameter, `--config cleanup.policy=compact`, in your answer.

Comment: I just want to add that also in the confluent documentation  for CDC Oracle they talk about that https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-oracle-cdc/current/troubleshooting.html#this-record-has-failed-the-validation-on-broker-and-hence-will-be-rejected Maybe this can help to someone